# HTML EMAIL with absolute image links - Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, html-email

I'm trying to send html email with following content:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://www.xyz.com/uploads/images/abc.JPG" style="width: 400px; height: 225px;" /></p>
```

but not getting send? i have no options to make images as attachment because i'm using html editor to put n upload images in content, and saving this html content to send as email.

Normal html email is getting send properly but not when i include any image with direct url to their location.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't even send the email with an image URL?

Comment: It does send email, i don't get any error or exceptions but after sending i don't receive them in my inbox, but emails without img tag delivers just fine.

Comment: Have you set the content type to "text/html"? For example, `message.setContent("<h1>Hello world</h1>", "text/html");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

however issue is solved now, i was setting message body directly in MimeMessage object with setContent method, doing it with Multipart and MimeBodyPart fixed the problem.